How do I mount multiple circuit boards in a project box?
What's the best way to mount multiple, different sized, circuit boards in a project box? For example, I have a new project that requires a relay module board, a DFPlayer Mini MP3 player board, a Jemmy Talk board, and a small breadboard to provide power to these three from a single power source.
If it matters, the box will have power coming in from a wall wart, and 3 sets of two output wires (6 total).
The question is not how to fasten a circuit board into a project box, but rather, when multiple boards go into the same box, and they are different sizes, what are the options and pros and cons of each? Besides just a flat, horizontal layout, do some people mount on edge for their home hobby projects? Mound one on top of another, fastening only one or two standoffs where the holes overlap? One flat, one on edge? If mounting on edge, as the enclosure isn't custom, with matching rails, how do you mount them?
THIS QUESTION OS DIFFERENT from How to Mount a PCB in a Project Box because my question is how to layout, arrange, and attach multiple, differently sized circuit boards, not just a single PCB.

question edited to explain why it is different.

If you're designing them yourself and you want to stack them, design them so the mounting holes do line up. If you're mounting boards you didn't design, then it all comes down to how clever you are.

@ViennaMike This question needs to be more specific, there are many different ways to mount PCB's and it's very project dependent. Describe your project, the constraints and what you have in mind.
